# How to read a file which has been excluded from resources folder in Maven's POM.xml

Tags: java, maven, resources

I need help here. I have few files in my resources folder which are useful during the application's run time and are also static, however, one of the files is user-dependent, if more data needs to be added/removed. So, I excluded this file from resources folder in my POM.xml as below:-

```
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/inputdata.csv</exclude>
        </excludes>
```

So, now the Jar file maven creates, this file is not a part of that JAR file. When I run the program in eclipse, Eclipse continues to read this resource file as it still lies in the resource folder. but, JAR file fails to run as it can't find this file anywhere.

Here is my problem - Where do I store this file so that Eclipse also runs as usual and so does my JAR file and also it remains outside my JAR file so that it can be edited whenever required.

Comment: What do you mean by "Eclipse also runs this jar ? Does you mean running tests from Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to set a file location as an argument to main method.. 
If this file is critical in sense of luck, throw a RuntimeException

Answer (score 1):

specify the file location in java classpath such as java -cp "C:\inputdata.csv" myjar.jar

Comment: Okay and then, what are the next steps?

Comment: @BharatNanwani once the csv is available on your classpath in above fashion, you can load it using getResourceAsStream()